# Cannot register assembly

Tags: c#-4.0, dll, .net-assembly

I have a Windows application on C# and some console application.

In that solution I have two libraries named A and B.

Library A is using reference of Library B.

But when I built my application I got the error below:-

```
Cannot register assembly "A.dll". Could not load file or assembly
"B.dll" or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a circular reference? Check your library B does not hold a reference to A.

If that isn't the case, right click on your solution name. 
Select 'Project Dependencies'; 
Select Project A and tick project B to set it as the dependency.

See the other tab 'Build Order' and make sure Project B is above project A.

If this doesn't solve your problem, Go to each project properties; 
Set 'Target Framework' in Application pane and 'Platform Target' in Build pane are same for those projects.

Answer (score 0):

For the win console application copy all .dll to location .exe and then test to run from 
window command (cmd), after run you still get the same previous error "Cannot register assembly A.dll. Could not load file or assembly B.dll" I think the .dll was build under
Dot net framework you are using on project. Example sometime you cannot reference .dll Dot net 2.0 with the project Dot net framework 4.0

Aey.Sakon